# Eclipse gradle plugin: Gradle dependencies sometimes changes positon in 'order and export' screen

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dependencies, gradle

I'm using gradle with eclipse (3.7) and the gradle eclipse plugin.
To have my code compiling Ok, I must have the gradle dependencies as the top (first) dependencies in 'order and export' in eclispe build path - 'order and export' screen
I've an annoying problem that sometimes the 'Gradle dependencies' position changes and it is not the first dependency which causes my code not to compile/run.

running gradle->refresh dependencies or just redefine the 'Gradle dependencies' to be top dependency usually fix it but it is annoying to do it each time.

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent it from happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved after upgrading the eclipse gradle plugin to the new version 2.9